# Adding '$' sign for amount field

Tags: c#, oracle

I am generating a report using C# and want to have '$' sign in the amount field. How can I append $ sign before the amount field.

Please help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The [Currency format specifier (C)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#currency-format-specifier-c) doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged the question with Oracle tag as well, see if `TO_CHAR` function with appropriate format model helps.

For example:

```
SQL> select sal,
  2         to_char(sal, '$999G990D00') formatted_salary
  3  from emp
  4  where rownum = 1;

       SAL FORMATTED_SALARY
---------- ----------------
       840          $840,00

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you..This query worked in Oracle but when I wrote this query in my code I am getting error "Unable to find definition $999G990D00".Can you please help.

Comment: Well, that's a valid format model as far as Oracle is concerned. Unfortunately, I don't know C#, and error you got seems to be related to it.

Answer (score 1):

Change at *SQL Syntax* and get output

```
SELECT sal,
       TO_CHAR(to_number(sal, 'L99999', 'NLS_CURRENCY=''$'''), 
              'L99999',
              'NLS_CURRENCY=''Rs. ''') AS "AnnualSalary"
  FROM Salary
```